# Extract music files from a Audio CD

Tags: audio, mp3, ripping, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What good, free audio CD ripping/extraction tools exist for Windows, and supporting multiple formats?](https://superuser.com/questions/2100/what-good-free-audio-cd-ripping-extraction-tools-exist-for-windows-and-supporti)

I have an audio cd, which has audio files with the file format as **.cda**  ( CD Audio Track ).

Each one of these files have a size of 1 KB each, and the rest of the CD has nothing else.

Is there a way that I can
**get the audio files from the CD

and

then convert it into mp3 format** and then play it in any other devices as I like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite tool for audio extraction has been [CDeX](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/) for years, but [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) is also very good. They will both extract to mp3 in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Thats called ripping - there's about a billion different softwares for doing it - i personally use [fre:ac](http://www.freac.org/) to do it. pop in the disc, run the software, and that's about it.